# Bluemix Node-RED Flow Editor Deleted

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I have deleted the link on my index.html page to the Node-RED flow editor.

I don't want the public to access this link.

How would I gain access to the flow editor, now that it has been deleted?

Under Start Coding, the directions for ***Start coding with Node-RED***

1. After your application has started, click on the Routes URL or enter the following URL in a browser: http://yourhost.mybluemix.net
   The Node-RED landing page displays.
2. Click Go to your Node-RED flow editor. This opens up a browser-based flow editor that makes it easy to wire together devices, APIs, and online services by using the wide range of nodes included in its palette.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it in my history.

http://projectname.mybluemix.net/red

Answer (score 3):

Rather than delete the link why not follow the advice in the box under that link about how to secure access to the editor

Answer (score 2):

This is not a correct way to do your node red flows private. An idea is using the SSO service to protect your site. Bind the service to your app and then you can configure the service adding a "Cloud Directory" user. You can read more details about SSo here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/configure_service.html#task_cloud_is

To use a Node.js app (developed with Express 3.x) with the Single Sign On service, you must make some modifications to its code (https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/SingleSignOn/ts_index.html)